# Wrong Profile url in careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

If I edit my careers header part there is a field for `Custom Profile Url` and the preview below is:

> Prod.careers.stackoverflow.com/l33tname

Which should be careers.stackoverflow.com/l33tname

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it's a bug though. Maybe careers.so.com/someone doesn't work somehow.

Comment: Well the Prod in the url looks a bit like they have different environments so I guess `Prod.careers.stackoverflow.com` works fine internal but it's not a external url

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M interesting to mention, dev.careers.stackoverflow.com does exist. (and of course is password protected :))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know. We switched over from our New York data centre to our Denver one recently, and this was a small difference in configuration between the two environments. I've corrected the setting now.